# What does a single CR mean ? (telnet)

Tags: telnet, specifications, rfc

RFC854 specifies, that a CR NUL means a carriage return to the same line and CR LF means a newline.

What does it mean, if a single CR is transmitted its own? (If it is followed by something not a being \0 or \n?)

Comment: A `CR` alone, return to the beginning of the current line, so the line is deleted.

Comment: It probably means that the sender didn't read the Telnet specification, so just treat it as a normal every-day carriage return.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Does it mean, that the line is deleted or that the cursor is moved to the beginning of the line? And if it means the latter, will subsequent characters inserted or overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

From the RFC:

| NAME | CODE | MEANING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL (NUL) | 0 | No Operation |
| Line Feed (LF) | 10 | Moves the printer to the next print line, keeping the same horizontal position. |
| Carriage Return (CR) | 13 | Moves the printer to the left margin of the current line. |

So `NUL` is the ascii character `NULL` i.e. code 0.

> However, many systems and
> terminals do not treat CR and LF independently, and will have to
> go to some effort to simulate their effect.  (For example, some
> terminals do not have a CR independent of the LF, but on such
> terminals it may be possible to simulate a CR by backspacing.)
> Therefore, the sequence "CR LF" must be treated as a single "new
> line" character and used whenever their combined action is
> intended; the sequence "CR NUL" must be used where a carriage
> return alone is actually desired; and the CR character must be
> avoided in other contexts.  This rule gives assurance to systems
> which must decide whether to perform a "new line" function or a
> multiple-backspace that the TELNET stream contains a character
> following a CR that will allow a rational decision.

So here:

- `CR LF` means new line
- `CR NUL` means carriage return (same line)
- `CR` (alone, without `LF` or `NUL`) must be avoided

> Note that "CR LF" or "CR NUL" is required in both directions
> (in the default ASCII mode), to preserve the symmetry of the
> NVT model.  Even though it may be known in some situations
> (e.g., with remote echo and suppress go ahead options in
> effect) that characters are not being sent to an actual
> printer, nonetheless, for the sake of consistency, the protocol
> requires that a NUL be inserted following a CR not followed by
> a LF in the data stream.  The converse of this is that a NUL
> received in the data stream after a CR (in the absence of
> options negotiations which explicitly specify otherwise) should
> be stripped out prior to applying the NVT to local character
> set mapping.

Comment: But what should the receiver do, if something is send, that "must be avoided", but is not forbidden?

Comment: I don't know. My interpretation is that is is required. And if you receive something illegal it should be ignored. But this is based on a terse reading of the rfc.

Comment: Now I wonder, whether this is symmetrical to LF. Is this also vague, or is it defined to mean same column one line down?

Comment: @Caulder I don't know. I read the same rfc as you. I don't have any other insight.

Comment: I see. But clients seam to have agreed on this? Or does everyone implements this how he likes?

Comment: @Caulder no ideea